# SQL table names with spaces

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, keyword, quoted-identifier

I have a table name with spaces between say like 'Orders Details'.

I want to use that table in stored procedures with joins.I have tried using alias names,[],`` in queries but nothing seems to be working.Can anybody help me on this error!

[image]

Comment: `ORDER` is a T-SQL keyword and can't be used as an alias without escaping. The problem in your query is not `Orders Details` (that's properly escaped). You don't need to alias `Orders` in the first place, so removing that and joining on `Orders.OrderID` should work.

Comment: The problem is not with `[Order Details]`, is with the alias `order` (it's a reserved word)

Comment: _Reserved_ keywords can't be used as identfiers, unless delimited. E.g. `[order]`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `order` as a column alias.  It is a SQL keyword.  I would just use `o`:

```
select o.*, od.*
from orders o join
     order_details od
     on o.orderid = od.orderid
where year(o.orderdate) = @orderyear;
```

Notes:

- Your `JOIN` condition is on `ProductId`.  However, that is highly suspicious.  Usually such joins are on the order id.  In fact, `ProductId` doesn't belong in `Orders` (usually) if there is a detail table.
- Do not define your tables with spaces in the name.  That just makes it hard to reference the names.
- `orderdate` does not seem to be defined, because it has a red underline.
- I don't recommend `select *`.  For one thing, you will have duplicate column names.  More importantly, you want to be explicit about what this code returns, particularly in a stored function or procedure.